# android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" don't work for <ExpandableListView

Tags: android, background, scroll, expandablelistview

I'm using an ExpandableListView, when is expanded and scrolling, it turns  black for a second when the scroll finishes. I used "android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" but It seems not work for expandable listview. The code is:

```
    <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp" android:divider="@color/color_negro"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" android:childDivider="@color/color_negro"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" android:background="@null">
    </ExpandableListView>
```

and for to draw each child:

```
            public View newChildView(boolean isLastChild, ViewGroup parent) {
                if(layoutInflater == null){
                    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                }
                return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_personas, null, false);
            }
```

Code for row_personas.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@layout/custom_text_view_apellido"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
>

<TextView android:id="@+id/rowApellido" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/color_negro"
android:textSize="14sp" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp" android:paddingRight="4dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp" android:typeface="sans"
android:maxLength="20" >
</TextView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/rowNombres" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textSize="14sp"
android:textColor="@color/color_negro" android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:maxLength="20"
android:singleLine="true" android:typeface="sans" android:paddingTop="0dp" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/photo" android:layout_height="34dp"
android:layout_width="41dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:layout_marginRight="2dp" />

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:id="@+id/rowDatoRelevante"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@color/color_gris_oscuro"
android:textSize="12sp" android:paddingLeft="15dp"
android:paddingTop="1dp" android:paddingBottom="1dp"
android:background="@layout/custom_text_view_categoria"
android:gravity="left" android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
android:singleLine="true">
</TextView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/rowDatoRelevante2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textStyle="italic" android:textColor="@color/color_gris_oscuro"
android:textSize="12sp" android:paddingLeft="15dp"
android:background="@layout/custom_text_view_categoria_desc"
android:gravity="left" android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
android:singleLine="true">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If someone can help me...Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

I resolved my problem!!! I changed the declaration of ExpandableListView in this way:

```
<ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" android:divider="@android:color/black"
android:childDivider="@android:color/transparent"
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">
</ExpandableListView>
```

I think that the problem was assign black color to "android:childDivider". I hope to help someone with this!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix a similar bug by drawing a *9 patch png* and setting it as the `childDivider`. My 9 patch png is two pixels high: the first row is set to the desired divider color, the second - stretchable one - to transparent.